# Saving JPG encoded array from a ROS sensor_msgs/CompressedImage to a file in roscpp

Tags: c++, jpeg, ros

I have a Robot Operating System (ROS) .bag file containing .jpg compressed images in the form of sensor_msgs/CompressedImage messages. I have written a roscpp program that can access the raw data in the individual messages, but I'm having a hard time saving the array of raw jpg encoded data into a file.

Unfortunately, the bag files I have are very large and contain thousands of images, and I am working under a time constraint. I tried using rosbag play -i and image_view export to save off the images, but it's way too slow. I also tried using Python, but Python is slow, and I don't have a way to save the images (same problem as in C++).

Essentially, I need a way to prepend a valid jpg header to my data and save it in a file. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Trying to synthesise a jpeg header seems like the wrong way to go... all the information you need must already been in the source data, or how else would those tools be able to display them to you?

Comment: The source data gives me an array of bytes, a time stamp, and tells me that the data is bgr8 jpg encoded. I guess it's possible I could just save the array to a file and see if that works?

Comment: Its worth a try. If you have a look at the initial and final byte values you could check the jpeg magic numbers, too... a jpeg file should start with `FF D8` and end with `FF D9`

Comment: It does! Great. Should be easy then :D

Comment: Mystery solved. I'll add that as an answer, in case it is of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an image header for a chunk of data that should already be an image is probably not the right approach. After all, jpegs are complex and the datastream should have all the information needed to decode them... how else would those tools be able to display them to you?

You can get a good idea of whether or not a binary blob contains an image by looking at the first and last bytes. Jpegs start with `FF D8` and end with `FF D9`, for example. Some of the magic numbers for other files can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files